# Python Cant exit a Pygame game

Tags: python, pygame

I recently finished a game from an online course and I've been adding some features to it, but the one feature that i can't execute was to exit the window by clicking the close button. The game runs perfectly but the Quit event doesn't execute. I tried adding a print function at the if statement in the handle_event function to see if it will print out a statement whenever the Quit event is triggered and it doesn't. Here is the code, i removed the unimportant codes, the close functions is in the handle_event function.

```
# Hacking Version 9
# This is a graphical password guessing game that displays 
# an embedded password from a list of potential computer 
# passwords. The player is allowed up to 5 attempts to guess 
# the password. Each time the user guesses incorrectly, 
# the number of correct letters in their correct locations is 
# displayed and the user is prompted to make a new guess. 
# The game indicates whether the player successfully 
# guessed the password or not.

from uagame import Window
from time import sleep
from random import randint, choice, sample
from pygame import QUIT
from pygame.event import get as get_event

def main():
    location = [0, 0]    
    attempts = 5
    window = create_window()
    create_game(window, location, attempts)

def create_window():
# Create a window for the game, open it and return it

    window = Window('Hacking', 600, 500)
    window.set_font_name('couriernew')
    window.set_font_size(18)
    window.set_font_color('green')
    window.set_bg_color('black')
    return window

def create_game(window, location, attempts):
# Create game, checks if close button is not clicked and
# executes the game
    while True:
        handle_event(window)
        play_game(window, location, attempts)
            
def play_game(window, location, attempts):
# Play the game

    display_header(window, location, attempts)
    password = display_password_list(window, location)
    guess = get_guesses(window, password, location, attempts)
    end_game(window, guess, password)

def handle_event(window):
# handles pygame Quit event

    for event in get_event():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            window.close()            

def display_header(window, location, attempts):
    pass
def display_password_list(window, location):
    pass
def embed_password(password, size):
    pass
def get_guesses(window, password, location, attempts_left):
    pass
def check_warning(window, attempts_left):
    pass
def display_hint(window, password, guess, location):
    pass
def end_game(window, guess, password):
    pass
def display_outcome(window, outcome):
    pass
def display_line(window, string, location):
    pass
def prompt_user(window, prompt, location):
    pass

main()
```

Comment: TL;DR of the duplicate question: `window.close()` is not sufficient; use `sys.exit()`.

Comment: I don’t believe this is a duplicate of that, since OP states that they tried printing if the event is triggered in the first place, and it doesn’t, so that’s the problem.

Comment: My theory is that you’re doing something with “uagame” that triggers its functionality that drops events. This function for instance looks like it would drop all other events because it calls _get_key: https://github.com/Aarowaim/snek/blob/20d4a2b44f5e5ddebf8e1c1c4c8d341d78e18a24/uagame.py#L138

Comment: Use `if event.type in (QUIT, WINDOWCLOSE):` and `from pygame import WINDOWCLOSE` . However, just closing the window will give you an error message, so make sure you end the game before you do that. A hardcore version is to `import sys; sys.exit()` instead of window.close()